# Retrieving system calls with Ptrace, stopping after first one

Tags: c++, c, linux, kernel, ptrace

I am trying to retrieve all of the numbers of system calls and eventually the names of the system calls called by a give program using ptrace.  I am on a 64 bit system so I am using the ORIG_RAX * 8 to find system calls using ptrace. I currently can only retrieve the first system call, output of a sample run is below. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Output:
    griffinm@well $ g++ mystrace.cc

```
~/cs153/assn2
griffinm@well $ a.out ls
Please wait
The child made a system call 59
a.out  mystrace.cc  mystrace.cc~
Number of machine instructions : 252376
~/cs153/assn2



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define ORIG_RAX 120 

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
        long long counter = 0;  /*  machine instruction counter */
        int wait_val;           /*  child's return value        */
        int pid; 
    long orig_eax;               /*  child's process id          */

        puts("Please wait");

    switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
            perror("fork");
            break;
    case 0:
            ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);

            execvp(argv[1],  NULL);

            break;

    default:
            wait(&wait_val); 

    orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                      pid, ORIG_RAX,
                      NULL);
    printf("The child made a "
           "system call %ld\n", orig_eax);

            while (wait_val == 1407 ) {
                    counter++;

                    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, pid, 0, 0) != 0)
                            perror("ptrace");

                    wait(&wait_val);

            }

    }
    printf("Number of machine instructions : %lld\n", counter);
    return 0;
```

}

```
Update Default Case:
Default:     
            wait(&wait_val); 


            while (wait_val == 1407 ) {
                    counter++;

                    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) != 0)
                            perror("ptrace");
         orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                      pid, 8*ORIG_RAX,
                      NULL);
        cout<<orig_eax<<endl;
                    wait(&wait_val);

            }

    }
```

Edit:

```
Output:

griffinm@well $ a.out pwd
Please wait
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
/home/csmajs/griffinm/cs153/assn2
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

I think the 8*Orig_RAX is the problem, the machine is 64 bit like I said. Any ideas?

Comment: You should not be hard-coding the number 1407 to compare the return value of [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) against—that's an implementation detail.  Instead, you should be testing `while (WIFSTOPPED(wait_val) && WSTOPSIG(wait_val) == SIGTRAP)`.

Comment: Thanks! My professor gave us some skeleton code with that for the while loop condition. I had a feeling there was a way to make it more general.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `PTRACE_SYSCALL` instead of `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP` to run the child up to the next system call rather than just a single instruction.  Then you can use the `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` again to see what syscall it is.

Comment: I tried that and posted the updated results in my original question